# WPF - How can I display a column in a datagrid with animated gif and normal png depending the value of field?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, datagrid, animated-gif

I have a WPF DataGrid in my application and one column display the status the processing of some jobs (success, fail or executing). The success and fail status are a png file (still image) and executing status I'd like to be a animated gif.
But, my code has some problems.

**First:** I want to call the images as Application Resource. With the PNG files is OK. But the GIF file doesn't display at the screen. How could I reference it at App.xaml?

**Second** issue: What do I need doing to ONLY animated gif rotate? The png images also rotating :(

Can anyone try to help me? 
Thanks :)

Here's the **xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.ListJobsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">

     <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Spin360" Storyboard.TargetName="Spinner" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListJobs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:StatusJobConverter x:Key="StatusJobConverter"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Name="Spinner" Source="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusJobConverter}}" Width="16" Height="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                            <Image.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Spin360}" />
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Image.Triggers>
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the **StatusJobConverter** class:

```
public class StatusJobConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is StatusJob)
        {
            StatusJob status = (StatusJob)value;
            return this.GetIcon(status);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private object GetIcon(StatusJob statusJob)
    {
        switch (statusJob)
        {
            case StatusJob.Success:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("success");
            case StatusJob.Error:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("error");
            case StatusJob.Executing:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("executing");
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="success"    UriSource="/MyApplication;component/images/success.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="error"      UriSource="/MyApplication;component/images/error.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="executing"  UriSource="/MyApplication;component/images/spinner.gif" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Your Template will rotate no matter what you load in there as it relies on Loaded event rather than a `DataTrigger`. Have a look the the `EnterAction` in [this MSDN post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes). You have done almost everything, well done.

Comment: I try to change the Event.Trigger to Data.Triggers but raise an exception on initialize the application.
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Executing"><DataTrigger.EnterActions><BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Spin360}" /></DataTrigger.EnterActions></DataTrigger></Image.Triggers>

Comment: Finally I got. Tks XAMlMAX, I've put the DataTrigger inside a style